# Piping in a while loop C

Tags: c, shell, pipe

Im working on a shell that can handle pipes.  the problem im runing into now is that when a pipe is found after both are done executing my shell exits.  This is some sample code ive been working on to try and figure

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t pid2;
    int childSt;
    int hell;
    struct arguments args;
    char line[1024];

    while (fgets(line, 1024, stdin)) {
        line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////          /
        args = finArgs(line);
        pipe(fd);
        pid = fork();
        if (pid > 0)       // PARENT 
        {
            pid2 = fork();
            if(pid2 == 0){
                close(fd[1]);   //close write end 
                if (fd[0] != STDIN_FILENO) 
                {
                    if ((dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO)) != STDIN_FILENO)
                    {
                        printf("dup2 error to stdin\n");
                        close(fd[0]);   
                    }
                }
                if (execvp(args.pipeArgs[0], args.pipeArgs) < 0)
                    printf("parent error \n");                
            }
            else {
                wait(&childSt);
            }
        }

        else    // CHILD
        {
            close(fd[0]);
            if (fd[1] != STDOUT_FILENO)
            {
                if ((dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO)) != STDOUT_FILENO)
                {
                    printf("dup2 error to stdout\n");
                    close(fd[1]);
                }
            }
            if (execvp(args.args[0], args.args) < 0)
                printf("child error \n");   
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

here is some sample output

```
ls | wc
     14      14     123
```

this is what i want but then the program exits.

Comment: The execvp in the parent process is the problem.  The execvp call will execute whatever it is that you're having it do, and then it exits completely.  The execvp call will ONLY return if it is in error.  It's basically saying, "go do this and quit when you're done".  Reference: [http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp)

Comment: OK i can understand why that happens.  Is there a way i can return to the while loop?

Comment: There are a couple of solutions.  You could use the system() call, which will execute a program and return.  Or you could fork yet again and let the child process of that form perform the execvp.  That way, the parent could proceed forward...